# Newsstand free subscriptions

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, newsstand-kit

I'm developing app - it is custom offline feed reader. I's completely free, so I do not need any subscriptions. I want to use some newsstand features and I already draw amazing icon for newsstand:) What should I do? Is any workarounds about this issue? May be some "fake" free subscription?

Another issue - when I tried to publish app with only one free subscription, I failed. Is that normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your completely correct you can have free subscriptions, iTunes connectly clearly states you can have free subscriptions. 
If you want to use Urban airship [this guide](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/29/at-newsstand-and-subscriptions/) should help you out, and give you the perfect guide as to what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Search First Glimpse magazine. It is a free magazine that populates in News Stand. Also, that publishing company has more free content